# SecretKey generation for DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding

Tags: c#, java, encryption, des

I'm having problems when encrypting data to be sent to a SOAP service.

I suppose the problem is in the SecretKey generation, because the response is still the same with an incorrect password.

The current code is:

```
WServiceSoap ws = new WService().getWServiceSoap();
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");

byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("12345678".getBytes("utf-8"));

final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
  keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
}

SecretKey opKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");        
byte[] opIV = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };       
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, opKey, new IvParameterSpec(opIV));

byte[] encrypted = c.doFinal(
    ClientDirectOperacionCTMS.DATOS_OPERACION.getBytes("UTF-8"));

String encryptedDatosOperacion= Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
String result= ws.operacionCTMS(encryptedDatosOperacion);
System.out.println(result);
```

, and the exception is

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Server was unable to process request. ---> La operación de pago con tarjeta no ha sido satisfactoria. ---> Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string.
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:111)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
```

I have also tried this code without success:

```
final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(Base64.decodeBase64("12345678"), 24);
SecretKey opKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
```

The decryption done by the server is

```
CheckKey(ref rgbKey);
cryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
cryptoTransform = cryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor(rgbKey, s_rgbIV);
memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(
    memoryStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
{
    cryptoStream.Write(rgbEncryptedText, 0, rgbEncryptedText.Length);
}

originalText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

, where CheckKey is

```
        private static void CheckKey(ref Byte[] rgbKey)
    {
        if (rgbKey.Length > KEY_MAX_LENGTH)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref rgbKey, KEY_MAX_LENGTH);
        }
        else if (rgbKey.Length < KEY_MAX_LENGTH)
        {
            Byte fill = 0x41;
            Int32 offset = rgbKey.Length;

            Array.Resize(ref rgbKey, KEY_MAX_LENGTH);

            for (Int32 index = offset; index < KEY_MAX_LENGTH; index++)
            {
                rgbKey[index] = fill++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've simplified your code to remove the exception handling - more readable now. Hope that's ok.

Comment: Do you have full control over how the key is produced from the password? If so, we can recommend much more secure alternatives to just grabbing the bytes (e.g. PBKDF2).

Comment: Also, more importantly, do you have either the code for the web service you can share? Or at least a decent description of how it decrypts the data?